# Getting XXX in the output IR REGISTER = XXXXX

Tags: verilog

mY GOAL IS TO THE GET THE DATA AS INPUT AND STORE IT IN THE MEMORY I am storing it in Fetch_Memory and later and I am increment the pC value for every clock edge, i am doing a asynchronous read from the memory for the respective value.

```
  input clk;
    input [31:0] din;
    input reset;
    reg [31:0] PC = 31'b0;
    output reg [31:0] IR;

    integer counter = 512'b0; 
    parameter data_width = 32;
    parameter data_depth = 512;


  always @(posedge clk)
    begin 
        if(reset)
        begin 
            counter <= 512'b0;
            PC <= 32'd0;
    //      IR <= 32'd0;

        end
        else 
        begin 
        Fetch_Memory[PC] <= din;//din;
        counter <= counter + 512'h1;
        PC <= PC + 32'd1;  //32'h00000001;
    //  IR <= Fetch_Memory[counter];

        end

    end

    always @(posedge reset)
    begin 
        IR <= 32'b0;
    end
**//   thE PROBLEM IS iN HERE i AM gETIING xxxx VALUES IN THE IR REGISTER**
    always @(PC)
    begin 
        IR = Fetch_Memory[PC];

    end

    endmodule






   *`Here I am ADDING TH**E tEST BENCH TOO**`**     
parameter data_depth = 512;
parameter data_width = 32;
    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg [31:0] din;
    reg [31:0] PC;
    reg reset;

// Outputs
reg [31:0] IR;
integer counter ;
reg [data_width-1:0] Fetch_Memory [data_depth-1:0];

     always 
     begin 
     #5 clk = ~clk;


     end

        initial begin
            // Initialize Inputs
            #0 reset = 1;
            #15 reset =0;
            clk = 1'b0;
            din = 32'h25645878;

            // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
            #100;

            // Add stimulus here
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have IR being set in two `always` blocks; this is not possible in synthesis, as it does not model a hardware component.

```
always @(posedge reset)
    begin
        IR <= 32'b0;
    end
//   thE PROBLEM IS iN HERE i AM gETIING xxxx VALUES IN THE IR REGISTER**
always @(PC)
    begin
        IR = Fetch_Memory[PC];
    end
```

For a combinatorial (asynch) lookup just use:

```
always @* begin
  IR = Fetch_Memory[PC];
end
```

If IR is still X, it has to do with writing data to `Fetch_Memory`.